# jQuery and internet explorer (IE9) issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I am having a WTF moment here.

I have been working with jQuery since I don't remember. It could be that I am really tired and my brain is not working.

I have being working on a website since couple of months and for some reason I have not tested some of its functionality on internet explorer.

Yesterday I started to do so and for some reason `$(some_element).parent()` is not working.

I did setup an example page on my private server.

The code is

```
<html>

<header>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.js"></script>
</header>

<body>
    <div id="tester">
        <div id="tester2">
                <div id="tester3">
                    <div id="tester4">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function(){

        parent = $("#tester4").parent();
        $(parent).css("width", "800px");
        $(parent).css("height", "800px");           
        $(parent).css("border", "solid 1px red");

        console.log(parent);

    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: IE says errors on page: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 16 May 2012 20:55:57 UTC


Message: Not implemented

Line: 32
Char: 4
Code: 0
URI: http://www.web.senouci.org/

Comment: `$(parent)` should be `parent`, there's no need to turn a jquery object into a jquery object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't like the implicit declaration of `parent`. Try `var parent` to keep it out of the global scope.